# is there Eclipse useful Add On for AutoComplete function like xCode?

Tags: java, objective-c, eclipse

I've started up with developing Java.

However, These days I've started iPhone project and gave me lazy writing code;auto code generate functionality in xCode.

Are there any non-pay free edition add-on exist that does similar to xCode?
I mean, I do know Eclipse already has partial auto method look up when you put '.' (dot) token after class name which shows the list of methods.

thank you all.

Comment: It comes by default with eclipse

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but...  don't be afraid of buying tools for your profession.  Especially if they're significantly better than the free alternatives.

Comment: @colithium: Eclipse is pretty good already, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The functionality is called `content assist` in Eclipse. It comes as default.

To trigger content assist, normally you have to click `Ctrl+Space` (Windows/Linux). But as you said, on Java it will be auto-activated when user press `.`.

You can however change this behavior. Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist` and change the `Auto activation triggers for Java`.

For example to get the behavior of xCode, you could change it to `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.`

[image]

Comment: BRAVO the answer! I've using Eclipse for 3 years now and you taught me! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It comes by default with eclipse.

You need to press `.` then `ctrl + spacebar`

Answer (score 1):

If `ctrl + space` doesn't work, you may try `Alt + /`

Answer (score 0):

I used to think the autocompletion was slow, but it turns out you can make it instant. Go to Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Content Assist / Auto-Activation and decrease Auto activation delay to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [`Code Recommends`](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/). This is a very useful Eclipse plugin you must have.

One of my most favorite functionality is 
[`Subwords Completion`](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#subwords-completion) (*you don't need to remember exactly the first letter of method's name, just type in other whatever letter you remember even they're inside*).

It also offers many other functionality that may meet your need.