# Linux or Sublime Text tab-style auto complete for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to enable Sublime Text style tab-autocomplete in Eclipse. I've gotten very used to simply typing the first few letters of a variable name in Sublime, hitting `tab` to complete the variable name, and then moving on without thought. It's proving to be a tough muscle memory to break as I transition to Eclipse.

I know about `CTRL + Space` for bringing up the code completion menu for automatically generating certain attribute names and whatnot, but I'm more referring to that really quick completion of names while I type them.

Comment: Eclipse has 'Insert single proposals automatically', which might help you _slightly_ towards your goal of minimising keystrokes.  See Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist.

Comment: @GregKopff you're wrong! From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "What topics can I ask about here? [...] * software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: @LukasKnuth: withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a quick [eclipse hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758205/is-there-eclipse-useful-add-on-for-autocomplete-function-like-xcode) will work for you?

I have never used Sublime's autocomplete, but it sounds like Xcode has something similar. Just fill the "auto activation triggers" textbox with any/all characters that you'd want to toggle autocomplete.